# groupByKey with millions of rows by key

Tags: apache-spark

Context:

- Aggregation by key with potentially millions of rows by key.
- Add features in row. To do that we have to know the previous row (by key and by timestamp). For the moment we used groupByKey and do the work on the Iterable.

We tried:

- Add more memory to executor/driver
- Change the number of partitions

Changing the memory allowed to executor/driver worked. It worked only for 10k or 100k rows by key. What about millions of rows by key that could happend in the future.

It seems that there is some work on that kind of issues : https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/1977

But it's specific for PySpark and not for the Scala API that we used currently

My questions are:

- Is it better that I wait for new features that handle this kind of
  issues knowing that I have to work specifically in PySpark?
- Another solution would be to implement the workflow differently using some specific keys, values to handle my needs. Any design pattern for that. For example with the need to have the previsous row by key and by timestamp to add fetures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the change in question just makes PySpark work more like the main API. You probably don't want to design a workflow that requires a huge number of values per key, no matter what. There isn't a fix other than designing it differently.

I haven't tried this, and am only fairly sure this behavior is guaranteed, but, maybe you can `sortBy` timestamp on the whole data set, and then `foldByKey`. You provide a function that merges a previous value into a next value. This should encounter the data by timestamp. So you see row t, t+1 each time, and each time can just return row t+1 after augmenting it how you like.

Comment: Thx for the reply Sean. Didn't know about foldByKey, I'll try that. The problem still remain for aggregation on all the data by key. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: For the part where I need only the previous element, after some search a solution could be to use zipWithIndex to join two RDD: index and index+1 so that I have all the data that I need in one line. Lots of process for a simple need but I'm not sure if there is better solutions...